# How can we find random document matching given query and update it atomically in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

FindOneAndUpdate picks documents sequentially. Is there a way to pick a random document matching our query and update it atomically?

Answer (score 1):

To get a random document, use [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/).

To update it, use the aggregation pipeline in FindOneAndUpdate.

Comment: What if I am running two instances of my application and both instance get same document after sampling and tries to update it? I am guessing one of them is going to fail. How do tackle these type of situations?

Comment: My use case is something like this: sample to find a record -> try updating the doc -> if failed -> resample and retry updating the doc until success.

Comment: If there are two instances of application running and both application picks same document as part of sampling, and both application tries to update same document, then only the one which updated it first will succeed right? second operation will fail because the original record which it was trying to update has changed.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to update the same document twice.